# How to move to the next iteration in a loop and repeat a method multiple times?

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I am trying to repeat calling a method multiple times in a loop. However the below code executes everything at once and only once. The method I am trying to call is the "Test.main(args)" and the values I am trying to store in the ArrayList(creates everytime it loops) is the "temp" and "getCorrect" values. At the moment, the Test.main(args) only appears once, and this method has a NEXT button which I don't know how to make it when it's pressed, it will continue the loop iteration. Grateful if anyone could help. Thanks a lot.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    ArrayList matrix = new ArrayList();

    for(int i=0; i<value1; i++){
        matrix.add(new ArrayList());//
        Test.main(args);//method which I am trying to repeat 
        String temp = Test.getAnswer();
        String [][] getCorrect = SQL.getCorrectAnswer();//get values
        ((ArrayList)matrix.get(i)).add(getCorrect[i][0]);//store into Arraylist
        ((ArrayList)matrix.get(i)).add(temp);//store into Arraylist
    }
    System.out.println(matrix);
```

}

Comment: what is `value1`? And what exactly is the problem? if `value1` is larger than 1, it should execute several times...

Comment: value1 is just a variable that's been passed on from another class, it indicates how many times the loop has to run. The problem is that Test.main(args) only calls once.

Comment: How do you know it runs only once? Have you checked if value1 is greater than 1? Have you tried to replace value1 with a number, eg. 5, just to see if it runs more than 1 time?